# Handling missing input in bash script/command

Tags: bash, input

I am adding a script (command?) for a modified `head` command to my ~/.bashrc. It handles inputs as expected, both when manually entered, when derived from globbing, and when provided by stdin. However, if I forget to provide an argument to `headj`, my terminal hangs and can't be recovered with Ctrl-C.

Here is my code (with some calls to `echo` for debugging purposes:

```
headj(){
    echo "script makes it this far without arguments"
    IFS=" " read -r -a input <<< "${@:-$(</dev/stdin)}"
    echo "but but crashes before getting here"
    # 
    for i in ${input[@]}; do
        echo -e "███████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████"
        echo -e "headj $i start"
        head -50 "$i"
    done
}
```

And here is how it behaves:

```
$ headj list1
script makes it this far without arguments
but not this far
███████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████
headj list1 start
a
b

$ headj list*
script makes it this far without arguments
but not this far
███████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████
headj list1 start
a
b

███████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████
headj list2 start
c
d

$ ls -1 li* | headj
script makes it this far without arguments
but not this far
███████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████
headj list1 start
a
b

███████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████
headj list2 start
c
d

$ headj
script makes it this far without arguments
```

and that's where it hangs.

I've tried reading the inputs using `input=( ${@:-$(</dev/stdin)} )` but get the same error. Adding this code at the beginning of the script handles the error.

```
if [ -z ${*:+x} ]; then
    echo "headj requires at least one argument"
    return
fi
```

Is there a better way to do this? Also, is there a keyword I should be searching for this type of problem?

Comment: not answer to your question but please read how to loop over positional parameters https://stackoverflow.com/q/192249

Comment: @alecxs, thanks. For more complex scripts I use `while :; do; case $1 in; -a|--arg) OPTARG=$2 ... blah blah blah... ; shift;; esac; shift; done`, but that seems overkills in this case, especially since all arguments to `headj` will be treated the same and `headj` doesn't take any optional arguments.

Comment: ok i don't understand whats purpose of /dev/stdin. thought you could just use `"$@"` it contains all arguments passed to script (and you can check for `$1` or even set default `${1:-default}`)

Comment: @alecxs, `/dev/stdin` is needed to accept information from pipes. Also, can you be a little more specific in your suggestion regarding `"$0"? I just tried a number of different variations using `"$0"` or `$0`; not all of them worked for my simple test and I'm pretty sure many would fail with edge cases.

Comment: never used pipes in script, can't help with this. if we pass arguments `./script.sh ./dir1 "./dir 2"` we could just use it straight for example `find "$@"` (will work with spaces in folder names). so ${@:-$(</dev/stdin)} will use positional parameters, **or** (as default) read from stdin? then this is probably the reason because you didn't pipe anything

Comment: thats how i would do it, remove all options (and its values) from positional parameters, check $# if something left then treat "$@" as files, otherwise read from pipe only https://stackoverflow.com/a/48720056

Comment: Seems to work for me. Without arguments it stops to read from stdin, but ^C kills it as normal. Does interrupting with ^C work for you with other programs? If e.g. the interrupt key is disabled in the terminal settings, or SIGINT ignored, then ^C wouldn't work.

Comment: @Josh if your only goal is to override head default value -n10 you could just add it (head will use the last -n if passed multiple times) `head "$@" -n50; return $?`

Comment: btw i don't think `IFS=" "` is good way to handle file names (but i don't know your intention). Do you want `ls -1 li* | headj` to print first 50 file names of list (same behavior like for head), or do you want to execute `head -n50 $file` for each existing file?

Comment: @alecxs, as shown in my toy data, the desired outcome is for `ls -1 li* | headj` to print the first 50 lines of each file found by `ls -1 li*`.

Comment: @ilkkachu, interrupting with ^C does work for other programs. Thanks for your answer below. I will accept after I have a chance to test it.

Comment: See also [What's wrong with var=$(</dev/stdin) to read stdin into a variable?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/716438)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you only run it without arguments or a pipe on mistake, and don't want to write filenames to the function's stdin (why would you), I'd add a check to see if stdin is a tty:

```
headj() {
    local files=()
    if [ "$#" -gt 0 ]; then
        files=("$@")
    elif ! tty >/dev/null; then
        readarray -t files
    else
        echo "Will not read filenames from a tty!" >&2
    fi
    for file in "${files[@]}"; do
        echo "do something with $file..."
    done
}
```

So, this works:

```
$ ls *.txt |headj
do something with test.txt...
```

But this complains:

```
$ headj
Will not read filenames from a tty!
```

Note that the `read` command you used would split filenames with whitespace, so I'd avoid doing that, hence the condition on the number of arguments and the array above. `readarray` should read a list of newline separated items, which is what `ls` and `find` produce (when piped), but of course it means filenames with newlines embedded wouldn't work.

(Nitpicky perhaps, but I also wouldn't use `"$@"` in the argument to `<<<` or in an assignment, since it's supposed to produce multiple words, which it can't do in those cases. Using `<<< "$*"` would make it clearer that the intent is to combine the arguments to a single string.)

As for why ^C wouldn't work, I can't repeat that, it doesn't look like the function should do that.

Comment: That works perfectly! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I just learned how to add a function into bashrc. Thanks for that. Try this for your problem.

```
headj(){
  ARG=${1? Error. Please, provide the input file. Example: headj filename}
  #echo "script makes it this far without arguments"
  IFS=" " read -r -a input <<< "${@:-$(</dev/stdin)}"
  #echo "but but crashes before getting here"
  # 
  for i in ${input[@]}; do
    echo -e ""`enter code here`
    echo -e "headj $i start"
    head -50 "$i"
done}
```

```
$headj
```

bash: 1:  Error. Please, provide the input file. Example: headj  filename

Example with pipe

```
$echo "It works for me." > answer.txt
$ cat answer.txt
```

It works for me.

```
$headj  answer.txt  | awk '{print $_}'
```

headj answer.txt start

It works for me.

```
headj  answer.txt  | awk '{print $_}' | sed 's/me./me. It should work for you too./g'
```

headj answer.txt start

It works for me. It should work for you too.

Comment: Linuxes, did you test your code with any of the pipe examples in my question? It doesn't work.

Comment: @Josh, i tested it with pip and works fine.

Comment: @Josh, I noticed you are trying to use head on a variable ( not a file). While there may be a way to get it work I should point out head is designed to work with files. How about you temporarily save the output of any command to a file and use your code on it. Here is an example: $ ls  -1 *.txt>list | headj list && rm list

Comment: you did not pipe anything into headj

Comment: @alecxs, yes I just noticed that. Thanks. See my comment above.